# Why can't I forward engineer this?

Tags: mysql

Okay this is an update. I am using MySQL Workbench. This is what I am entering in while I forward engineer. Halfway through you will see the result after forward engineering.

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

USE `mh23202` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mh23202`.`Patient`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mh23202`.`Patient` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mh23202`.`Patient` (
  `Patient Number` INT NOT NULL,
  `First Name` TEXT NULL,
  `Last Name` TEXT NULL,
  `Date of Birth` DATE NULL,
  `Phone Number` INT NULL,
  `Email` TEXT NULL,
  `Gender` TEXT NULL,
  `Race` TEXT NULL,
  `Address` TEXT NULL,
  `Reason for Visit` TEXT NULL,
  `Primary Doctor` TEXT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Patient Number`),
  CONSTRAINT `Visit Number`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Patient Number`)
    REFERENCES `mh23202`.`Visits` (`Visit Number`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `Physician Number`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Patient Number`)
    REFERENCES `mh23202`.`Physician` (`Physician Number`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mh23202`.`Visits`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mh23202`.`Visits` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mh23202`.`Visits` (
  `Visit Number` INT NOT NULL,
  `Date of Visit` DATE NULL,
  `Time of Visit` TIME NULL,
  `Reason for Visit` TEXT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Visit Number`),
  CONSTRAINT `Patient Number`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Visit Number`)
    REFERENCES `mh23202`.`Patient` (`Patient Number`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `Physician Number`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Visit Number`)
    REFERENCES `mh23202`.`Physician` (`Physician Number`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mh23202`.`Physician`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mh23202`.`Physician` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mh23202`.`Physician` (
  `Physician Number` INT NOT NULL,
  `Specialty` TEXT NULL,
  `First name` TEXT NULL,
  `Last Name` TEXT NULL,
  `Date of Birth` DATE NULL,
  `Phone Number` INT NULL,
  `Email` TEXT NULL,
  `Gender` TEXT NULL,
  `Race` TEXT NULL,
  `Address` TEXT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Physician Number`),
  CONSTRAINT `Visit Number`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Physician Number`)
    REFERENCES `mh23202`.`Visits` (`Visit Number`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mh23202`.`Medication`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mh23202`.`Medication` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mh23202`.`Medication` (
  `Prescription Number` INT NOT NULL,
  `Prescription Name` TEXT NULL,
  `Units per Day` TEXT NULL,
  `Start Date` DATE NULL,
  `Finish Date` DATE NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Prescription Number`),
  CONSTRAINT `Patient Number`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Prescription Number`)
    REFERENCES `mh23202`.`Patient` (`Patient Number`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `Physician Number`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Prescription Number`)
    REFERENCES `mh23202`.`Physician` (`Physician Number`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mh23202`.`MedicalRecord`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mh23202`.`MedicalRecord` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mh23202`.`MedicalRecord` (
  `Physician Number` INT NULL,
  `Date of Visit` DATE NULL,
  `Time of Visit` TIME NULL,
  `Reason for Visit` TEXT NULL,
  `Findings` TEXT NULL,
  `Notes` TEXT NULL,
  `Treatment` TEXT NULL,
  `Prescriptions` TEXT NULL,
  `Procedures` TEXT NULL,
  INDEX `Patient Number_idx` (`Physician Number` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `Patient Number`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Physician Number`)
    REFERENCES `mh23202`.`Patient` (`Patient Number`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mh23202`.`Nurse`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mh23202`.`Nurse` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mh23202`.`Nurse` (
  `Nurse Number` INT NOT NULL,
  `First Name` TEXT NULL,
  `Last Name` TEXT NULL,
  `Date of Birth` DATE NULL,
  `Phone Number` INT NULL,
  `Email` TEXT NULL,
  `Gender` TEXT NULL,
  `Race` TEXT NULL,
  `Address` TEXT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Nurse Number`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mh23202`.`Secretary`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mh23202`.`Secretary` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mh23202`.`Secretary` (
  `Secretary Number` INT NOT NULL,
  `First Name` TEXT NULL,
  `Last Name` TEXT NULL,
  `Date of Birth` DATE NULL,
  `Phone Number` INT NULL,
  `Email` TEXT NULL,
  `Gender` TEXT NULL,
  `Race` TEXT NULL,
  `Address` TEXT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Secretary Number`),
  CONSTRAINT `Visit Number`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Secretary Number`)
    REFERENCES `mh23202`.`Visits` (`Visit Number`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mh23202`.`ChargeNurse`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mh23202`.`ChargeNurse` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mh23202`.`ChargeNurse` (
  `Charge Nurse Number` INT NOT NULL,
  `First Name` TEXT NULL,
  `Last Name` TEXT NULL,
  `Date of Birth` DATE NULL,
  `Phone Number` INT NULL,
  `Email` TEXT NULL,
  `Gender` TEXT NULL,
  `Race` TEXT NULL,
  `Address` TEXT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Charge Nurse Number`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mh23202`.`Shifts`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mh23202`.`Shifts` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mh23202`.`Shifts` (
  `Shift Number` INT NOT NULL,
  `Date of Shift` DATE NULL,
  `Time of Shift` TIME NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Shift Number`),
  CONSTRAINT `Secertary Number`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Shift Number`)
    REFERENCES `mh23202`.`Secretary` (`Secretary Number`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `Physician Number`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Shift Number`)
    REFERENCES `mh23202`.`Physician` (`Physician Number`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `Nurse Number`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Shift Number`)
    REFERENCES `mh23202`.`Nurse` (`Nurse Number`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `Charge Nurse Number`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Shift Number`)
    REFERENCES `mh23202`.`ChargeNurse` (`Charge Nurse Number`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB; 


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS; `
```

This is what comes as a result.

```
ERROR: Error 1005: Can't create table 'mh23202.visits' (errno: 121)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mh23202`.`Visits` (

  `Visit Number` INT NOT NULL,

  `Date of Visit` DATE NULL,

  `Time of Visit` TIME NULL,

  `Reason for Visit` TEXT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`Visit Number`),

  CONSTRAINT `Patient Number`

    FOREIGN KEY (`Visit Number`)

    REFERENCES `mh23202`.`Patient` (`Patient Number`)

    ON DELETE NO ACTION

    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,

  CONSTRAINT `Physician Number`

    FOREIGN KEY (`Visit Number`)

    REFERENCES `mh23202`.`Physician` (`Physician Number`)

    ON DELETE NO ACTION

    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

ENGINE = InnoDB



SQL script execution finished: statements: 7 succeeded, 1 failed



Fetching back view definitions in final form.

Nothing to fetch

Executing SQL script in server

ERROR: Error 1005: Can't create table 'mh23202.visits' (errno: 121)





CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mh23202`.`Visits` (

  `Visit Number` INT NOT NULL,

  `Date of Visit` DATE NULL,

  `Time of Visit` TIME NULL,

  `Reason for Visit` TEXT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`Visit Number`),

  CONSTRAINT `Patient Number`

    FOREIGN KEY (`Visit Number`)

    REFERENCES `mh23202`.`Patient` (`Patient Number`)

    ON DELETE NO ACTION

    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,

  CONSTRAINT `Physician Number`

    FOREIGN KEY (`Visit Number`)

    REFERENCES `mh23202`.`Physician` (`Physician Number`)

    ON DELETE NO ACTION

    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

ENGINE = InnoDB



SQL script execution finished: statements: 7 succeeded, 1 failed



Fetching back view definitions in final form.

Nothing to fetch
```

Comment: Please find a way to simplify this post...  (Go, hopefully, Red Sox!)

Comment: I don't know how to simplify this? I'm entirely new to database and I need to forward engineer my work. I have all the tables laid out and primary and foreign keys made. Every time I try forward engineering it though I get this syntax error.

Comment: You're missing the column names in the `FOREIGN KEY` constraints.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any difference between the 3 table definitions. Why did you post the same thing multiple times?

Comment: I apologize, it's the way it copy/pasted

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of errors on your script. Most of them is because your are creating tables with FOREIGN KEY but are not specifying them.For example on this create table statement below at the references section :

```
CONSTRAINT `Visit Number`
    FOREIGN KEY () 
    REFERENCES `mh23202`.`Visits` ()
```

The empty parentheses are your errors on every table. For the foreign key it should have the column name from the table and on the REFERENCES **`mh23202`.`Visits` ()** it should have the column name from that table.

Plus as said on the comments, there is just one create table on your script the others one is duplicated from the first one. Most likely the tool that you used did not work properly and tried to create the script for just one table.

**EDIT**

After your edit you have on your create table commands spaces in between the field names. It shouldn't have or it should be quoted with . As on your first create statement: Patient Number.

Comment: Can I change this by clicking the table then going to foreign key and clicking on a single foreign key, then checking the box under the column tab then selecting a reference from the referenced column tab? Because I had done this as well but it ended with another error 1005, cannot create table.

Comment: On that I cant help you since you did not say what tool you use. But you have to find on this tool the tables dependencies. From your script it should be Patient and Physician, check thoose two, check the references options and try it again.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL error code 121: Duplicate key on write or update

issue with the  FOREIGN KEY (`Visit Number`).

Answer (score 0):

You can't have constraints with the same name for example.

- Table mh23202.Physician has a constraint called "Visit Number".
- Table mh23202.Patient has a constraint called "Visit Number".
- Table mh23202.Secretary has a constraint called "Visit Number".

You always have to make sure that the constraint names are different else you will have this error. I had similar issue on workbench. I changed the names which solved the problem.